# SQL WHERE statement where string can differ maximum one char but otherwise be equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, string-search

I am trying to create a SQL WHERE statement to compare strings that its allowed that maximum one character is different but still must be same length. I have tried using substring search with LIKE command but it does not work well if the char that is different in the middle of the string etc. Strings that should match examples:

should match:
"ABC123" and "ABC023"
"ABC124" and "ABC125" etc

should not match

"ABC123" and "ACB132"

How can this be achieved with a SQL WHERE statement?

Comment: There's no cheap way. No matter what expression you end up using, it won't be able to use any indexes. How much data is there? You may be able to do what you want by processing the data in a Python script and calculating the "distance" (difference in characters) between strings. If you use SQL Server 2017 and later, you can run Python scripts through SQL Server's Python services, essentially a specialized Conda distribution for data science

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming* you are on on the latest version of SQL Server (2022 at time of writing), you could use `GENERATE_SERIES` to get a row for each character in your search string, and then use `STUFF` to replace each character in a position with a single character wildcard (`_`). Then you can use an `LIKE` inside an `EXISTS`:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(6) = 'ABC123';

SELECT YT.YourColumn
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,LEN(@YourString)) GS
             WHERE YT.YourColumn LIKE STUFF(@YourString,GS.value,1,'_'));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZkWrcy8O)

If you aren't in SQL Server 2022+ then you could use your own tally function to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a levenshtein distance function and then call that function in your WHERE clause.

```
CREATE FUNCTION edit_distance(@s1 nvarchar(3999), @s2 nvarchar(3999))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @s1_len int, @s2_len int
 DECLARE @i int, @j int, @s1_char nchar, @c int, @c_temp int
 DECLARE @cv0 varbinary(8000), @cv1 varbinary(8000)

 SELECT
  @s1_len = LEN(@s1),
  @s2_len = LEN(@s2),
  @cv1 = 0x0000,
  @j = 1, @i = 1, @c = 0

 WHILE @j <= @s2_len
  SELECT @cv1 = @cv1 + CAST(@j AS binary(2)), @j = @j + 1

 WHILE @i <= @s1_len
 BEGIN
  SELECT
   @s1_char = SUBSTRING(@s1, @i, 1),
   @c = @i,
   @cv0 = CAST(@i AS binary(2)),
   @j = 1

  WHILE @j <= @s2_len
  BEGIN
   SET @c = @c + 1
   SET @c_temp = CAST(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j+@j-1, 2) AS int) +
    CASE WHEN @s1_char = SUBSTRING(@s2, @j, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   IF @c > @c_temp SET @c = @c_temp
   SET @c_temp = CAST(SUBSTRING(@cv1, @j+@j+1, 2) AS int)+1
   IF @c > @c_temp SET @c = @c_temp
   SELECT @cv0 = @cv0 + CAST(@c AS binary(2)), @j = @j + 1
 END

 SELECT @cv1 = @cv0, @i = @i + 1
 END

 RETURN @c
END
```

```
create table table1 (
  id integer, 
  string1 varchar(50), 
  string2 varchar(50)
  );
```

```
insert into table1 values 
(1, 'ABC123', 'ABC023'),
(2, 'ABC123', 'ABC12'),
(3, 'ABC124', 'ABC125'),
(4, 'ABC123', 'ABC132');
```

```
select *
  from table1
 where dbo.edit_distance(string1,string2) <= 1
   and len(string1) = len(string2)
```

| id | string1 | string2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123 | ABC023 |
| 3 | ABC124 | ABC125 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qT9EBQfm)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but i'm guessing levenstein function is a bit of an overkill (and slow) for this task. You don't need whole shebang and can jump out much earlier,because diff > 1 isn't interesting